# Parse Cloud Code returns pointer instead of object after save

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

**Problem:**

I'm trying to return a full object, instead I keep getting a pointer back. I think it might be because I modify the object, then save, then return it in the response. How would I be able to modify, save, and return the full object and not the pointer?

**Code:**
Only relevant code is shown:

```
getPicture(username, {
  success: function (pictureObject) {
    response.success(pictureObject); //Always getting pointer
  },
  error: function (error) {
    response.error(error);
  }
});

...

function getPicture(username, callback) {
    var Pictures = Parse.Object.extend("Pictures");
    var pictures = new Parse.Query(Pictures);
    pictures.equalTo("username", username);
    pictures.find({
        success: function (results) {
                var object = results[0];
                object.increment("views", 1); 
                object.save(); //I think the issue is here
                callback.success(object);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            callback.error(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think that you have to write 
object.save().then(function(newObj){ callback.success(newObj);});

Comment: Thank you so much :). You should reply as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take the object after parse save it in the database.

try using

```
 object.save().then(function(newObject){
      callback.success(newObject);
 });
```

this will send the object after the save.